# Always getting "Socket Hang Up with 'ECONNRESET'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, post, econnreset

When trying to hit always get an error with the help of the callback method but always getting error & trying to call API in a POST HTTP Method in NodeJS, tried all solutions but got nothing.

```
exports.createWallet = function(user_id, password, callback) {

var api_code = config.blockchain.api_code;
var user = user_id;
var pwd = password;

var result;

const post_data = JSON.stringify({
    'api_code': api_code,
    'password': pwd,
    'user_id': user
});

const options = {

    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 8586,
    path: '/api/v2/create',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
    }
};

var request = https.request(options, function (response) {
});

request.on('error', function (error) {

    console.log(error);
});

// With http.request() one must always call request.end() to signify the end of the request - even if there is no data being written to the request body.
request.end();
};
```

> ```
> { Error: socket hang up
>
>     at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1120:19)
>     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
>     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
>     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
>     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
>     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9) code: 'ECONNR
> ESET' }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***//Just use without https & pass parameters in path***

```
var http = require("http");     
const options = {

    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 8586,
    path: '/api/v2/create?api_code='+api_code+'&password='+pwd+'&user_id='+user,
    method: 'POST',
};

var request = http.request(options, function (response) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In options, try adding `body: post_data`

Comment: const options = {

        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: 8586,
        path: '/api/v2/create?api_code'+api_code+'&password'+pwd+'&user_id'+user,
        method: 'POST',
        protocol: 'https:',
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
        strictSSL: false,
        body: post_data,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
        }
    };

Comment: add body: post_data, in options but getting same error again & again

Comment: and also try other option but getting same "Socket hang up with ECONNRESET"

Comment: One more thing, `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`. Apart from that, In your application, ensure whether your app expects any access_token or not. If so, whether it expect it as header or request url. Do this accordingly. And, Don't pass your post_data in request url. This is passed in body.

Comment: const options = {

        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: 8586,
        path: '/api/v2/create?api_code='+api_code+'&password='+pwd+'&user_id='+user,
        method: 'POST',
    };

    var request = http.request(options, function (response) { }

Comment: working in all API's case without use https, just use HTTP.